# Error when converting form Python 2. to Python 3

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

can you help me to convert this to python 3.5 ? I tried but it don't work. I did the following steps:

- I change the package md5 to hashlib
- I change all the  `id = md5.new("%s"%str(clf.get_params())).hexdigest()`              to   `id = hashlib.md5(("%s"%str(clf.get_params())).encode('utf-8') ).hexdigest()`

but I still have somme problems when I put a directory to these parameters

```
save_preds="",
save_params=""
save_test_only=""
clf_name="XX"
```

I have the folowing error when I put something in thise parameters:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Please see the code here:

[blend_proba.py](https://github.com/MLWave/Kaggle-Ensemble-Guide/blob/master/blend_proba.py)

Thanks,

cdk

Answer (score 0):

Replacing

```
clf_name="XX"
```

by

```
clf_name=b"XX"
```

would convert the strings into objects of type bytes. Whether those changes will be enough, I honestly have no idea.